# 'Sequence Contains No Sequence' Even While Using DefaultIfEmpty() with Average()

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I get the following error when I attempt to call Average() on a result set, even when I use DefaultIfEmpty().

## Some code that produces the error:

```
var Test = context.FuelRecords.Select(e => (double) e.MilesDriven).DefaultIfEmpty();
Console.WriteLine(Test.GetType());
foreach (var t in Test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
    Console.WriteLine(t.GetType());
}
var Test2 = context.FuelRecords.Select(e => (double)e.MilesDriven).DefaultIfEmpty().Average();
```

## The Output:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.Double]
0
System.Double
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'MileageCalculator.Models.MileageContext'.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements.
         at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements.
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing because every post I see related to this seems to have been fixed by chaining DefaultIfEmpty onto the Select().

I have tried specifying 0 as an argument to DefaultIfEmpty() to no avail. It seems like regardless of DefaultIfEmpty, the Average() call looks at the original select query.

Comment: You must have an item in the resulting select to apply average. It tells u also in the exception : Sequence contains no elements

Comment: @DA I believed that DefaultIfEmpty was supposed to return a Singleton set if the result set was empty?

Comment: Try use DefaultIfEmpty(new FuelRecord(){MilesDriven = 0 ...}).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Average` overload which accepts nullable values:

```cs
var result = context.FuelRecords
    .Select(e => (double?)e.MilesDriven).Average() ?? 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it, but I don't understand why. In the reference pages, it says "Returns the elements of an IEnumerable<T>, or a default valued singleton collection if the sequence is empty.". Shouldn't then context.FuelRecords.Select(e => (double)e.MilesDriven).DefaultIfEmpty(); return a singleton collection with the value of 0, which could then be used with Average(). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: 1 ) You have read documentation about `Enumerable`,  but should read about `Queryable` 2 ) `Average` in EF Core has different behavior it will throw if database returns NULL and `Average` is not nullable. `DefaultIfEmpty` is ignored from translation - no SQL equivalent.